# Highcharts zIndex of dataLabel vs renderer.rect vs tooltip

Tags: highcharts

I'm struggling to get my chart elements in the right Z order, in particular where I have `dataLabels` with `useHTML` enabled, and where I also add a rectangle via `chart.renderer.rect()`.  This is illustrated in the following jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/fk7b3cnz/

I want the rectangle to be above the main chart features (lines, labels), and for the tooltip to be above the rectangle (i.e. above everything).  I managed to get the tooltip to sit on top (*except for the margin around it... how do I fix that?*), but the data labels are sitting above the rectangle... the zIndex I set for the rectangle doesn't seem to have any effect.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    tooltip: {
      useHTML: true,
      formatter: function () {
        return '<div class="tooltip">value: ' + this.y + '</div>';
      }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                useHTML: true // need this to achieve the text formatting I want via appropriate html (not shown here)
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

}, function (chart) { // on complete

    chart.renderer.rect(100, 100, 100, 100, 5)
        .attr({
            'stroke-width': 2,
            stroke: 'red',
            fill: 'yellow',
            zIndex: 9998 // want this to be above chart features but below tooltip
        })
        .add();

});
```

CSS:

```
.highcharts-tooltip span {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid green;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.tooltip {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding zIndex manually you can use [Highcharts.SVGElement.toFront](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#toFront) method. The rectangle will be plotted above lines and other svg elements. However, data labels that are created using HTML will be always above other SVG elements (Since Highcharts v6.1.1 tooltip can be plotted above HTML content) as you can read in the Highcharts [documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting#html):

> "It will always be laid out on top of all other SVG content.
>   Specifically the tooltip may be rendered below the useHTML label.
>   Since Highcharts v6.1.1 this can be avoided by setting tooltip.outside
>   to true."

```
chart.renderer.rect(100, 100, 100, 100, 5)
   .attr({
     'stroke-width': 2,
     stroke: 'red',
     fill: 'yellow'
   })
   .add()
   .toFront();
```

Demo:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/m1wLdz2j/)

Comment: Thanks.  Hmm, it's a real shame that the data labels will always appear on top of the rectangle.  Since it is possible to make the *tooltip* appear on top of the labels, my gut feeling is that it should also be possible (with some hack) to make the rectangle appear on top of the labels?  Why not?  The tooltip looks very much like it is just a rectangle with some text inside?  Maybe it's possible somehow to add an html-based rectangle, like the tooltip?  In fact, in reality my rectangle is just a custom text box (it has text inside).

Comment: P.S. when I say "in reality my rectangle is just a custom text box" I mean that in my *actual* code (not this simple example) I'm adding a rectangle to the chart merely as a nice background to some custom text I'm adding to the chart... both using `chart.renderer`.  Maybe I'm doing that wrong, and should be adding these custom "message boxes" using html elements instead?  If so, need to figure out how...

Comment: The best way to add custom text with a background is just to use Highcharts annotations instead of renderer - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations. Then, data labels won't be rendered when annotation cover it. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/8pgevsyb/1/.

Comment: Ah, annotations look good... is there any way to centre an annotation horizontally and/or vertically in the chart?